# How to open port 1935 on Centos 5.7

Tags: networking, centos, media, ports

Have Error with connection to media Server Red5: Error: Connection Rejected: No Scope..."
Red5 is correctly installed as I have a preview of it on port 5080. What shall I typed in SSH Putty to allow that port be used for my Media Server? I think so there is a firewall on the media server blocking TCP traffic over port 1935.

Once Connecting I have got this error on SSH Putty:

"[/usr/local/red5/dist]# [WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 109.153.XXX.XXX : 50849 to domain.co.uk (in: 3557 out 3222 ), with id 22239832 due to long handshake
"

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` will open port 1935.